# Data subset on quantile 0.975 in R

Tags: r, subset

i have a dataframe called `tvdata` with a variable `basket` with numerical values in it and trying to create a subset of this dataset with a quantile 0.975.

I've used this code:

```
data <- tvdata[ basket < (quantile(basket, 0.975))]
```

where data should be my new data frame and `tvdata` is an existing one.

But it didn't work.

R gives me an error message

```
Object 'basket' was not found.
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: If basket is part of tvdata you have to address it with `tvdata$basket` or `tvdata[["basket"]]`.

Comment: `basket.975 <- tvdata[tvdata$basket < quantile(tvdata$basket, 0.975), ]`.

Comment: If you don't like repeating your dataset name, you can use dplyr: `data |> filter(basket < quantile(basket, 0.975))`.

Comment: Can one of the commenters please post an answer ... ?? Or, the OP could post a solution based on the comments.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you for your Help! It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments to the question ([Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875049/data-subset-on-quantile-0-975-in-r?noredirect=1#comment123517928_69875049) and [N_I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875049/data-subset-on-quantile-0-975-in-r?noredirect=1#comment123540279_69875049)), here is a way of subsetting by quantile.

```
basket.975 <- tvdata[tvdata$basket < quantile(tvdata$basket, 0.975), ]
```